# Pull from MySQL vs pull from filesystem

Tags: mysql, database, performance, file, hosting

If there were 1 million concurrent users visiting a website viewing different pages, which is going to cause a higher server load (i.e., slow down the sever)?

**Pull from MySQL**

- GET index.php?=page_id=1
- GET index.php?=page_id=2
- GET index.php?=page_id=etc...

or

**Pull static page from filesystem**

- GET page_1.html
- GET page_2.html
- GET page_etc...html

Comment: Static page is likely going to be faster than a DB hit, beyond that, we'd probably need more info on how you're caching things, how many files there are, etc.

Comment: @dfb There's actually not much info. Content is just plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The less overhead the better, so a stripped down web server will be faster.

I've worked on plenty of sites where we generated static HTML files from the database (daily, hourly, etc) as the pages weren't dynamic.